# modificar Id añadiendole un número diferente cada vez

Tags: jquery

como puedo hacer para modificar el valor de un id de un elemento generado previamente mediante la función `append()`.

Es decir, yo quiero que el usuario al clicar un botón cree un `div` pero cada `div` creado a de tener su propia `id`.

Para ello había pensado crear una variable que se vaya aumentando cada vez que se apriete el botón de crear los `div`. Y de alguna manera que no se como

```
var valor = 0;

$('#BotónCrear').click(function(){

        valor = valor +1;

        $('#ContenedorPrincipal').append('<div id="NuevoId"></div>');
});
```

Así siempre se generaría un `div`con el mismo `id` y yo quiero que sea algo como:

NuevoId+valor

Y así este sería, NuevoId1, NuevoId2, NuevoId3...

¿Como se hace para concatenar eso?

Salud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para concatenar cadenas no tienes más que utilizar el operador +:

```js
$(function(){
  var valor = 0;

  $('#BotónCrear').click(function(){
    valor = valor +1;
    $('#ContenedorPrincipal').append('<div id="NuevoId' + valor + '"></div>');
  });
  
  $('#MostrarIDs').click(function(){
    $('#ContenedorPrincipal div').each(
      (i,e) => $(e).text($(e).attr('id'))
    );
  });
  
});
```

```css
#ContenedorPrincipal{
  padding: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: block;
}

#ContenedorPrincipal div{
  border: solid 1px red;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 180px;
  height: 40px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ContenedorPrincipal"></div>
<button id="BotónCrear">Crear</button>
<button id="MostrarIDs">Mostrar IDs</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tomando en cuenta tu código quedaría así:

```
   $('#ContenedorPrincipal').append('<div id="NuevoId'+ valor + '"></div>');
```

Si utilizas un ciclo for te quedaría así:

```
  for (var i in result) {
   $('#ContenedorPrincipal').append('<div id="NuevoId' + i + '"></div>');
```

Saludos